# Angular 9 - build in production mode prints error messages to log

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading to angular 9, when I build my project in production mode I get this output-

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Compiling @angular/core : module as esm5
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Compiling @angular/common : module as esm5
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Compiling @angular/platform-browser : module as esm5
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : module as esm5
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Compiling @angular/common/http : module as esm5
[ERROR]
```

and so on..

Any reason why?

Comment: Are you using `webpack` ?

Comment: I am using angualr-cli, I am building the project through "ng build --prod". I thing angular is using webpack.

Comment: Try 'npm i' command in the project directory.

Comment: Are you using maven? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16940

Answer (score 0):

With angular 9 and ivy, you need a postinstall script to manage compatibility with libraries ( node_modules)
Add in your package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  }
}
```

and run npm install

You can look at : https://angular.io/guide/ivy

And make sure you have this compiler options in your tsconfig :

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks! I need to run this script every time I execute build?

Comment: This script will run on every npm install

Answer (score -1):

Update your TS version. Try 3.7.0

`npm install typescript@3.7.0`

Comment: I have "typescript": "~3.7.5".. to go back to 3.7.0?

Comment: You can try. I just encountered the same issues yesterday and fixed it by changing TS versions